# Small, Rechargeable LiPo and RPi 4B

Tags: power-supply, arduino, pi-4, battery, alternative-power

**I've started a new, more specific thread, [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/106572/how-to-wire-li-po-to-rpi-4b-so-that-it-doenst-obstruct-the-gpio-or-processor).**

---

I'm looking for a way to power my Pi 4B inside a 3d-printed laptop project (nothing has actually been started yet), and it would be great to hear what you think I should use and **how I would wire** it. Specifications:

1) I intend for all the pi's plugs to be accessible from the outside (except for GPIO and ribbon plugs), so some **soldering directly to the pi** is probably required. Or *way better*, and less permanent, I have seen some power supply converters that attach to the GPIO. (like the [LiPo SHIM](https://shop.pimoroni.com/products/lipo-shim): but... see point 2)

- Just thinking, I might not need to access the two mini HDMI's since there's problems anyways with using the ribbon cable monitor AND the HDMI ports simultaneously, therefore leaving the possibility of keeping the power plug on the pi on the inside? Use mobile phone battery pack then?

2) (Reference to the LiPo shim) It **must not cover the processor** (and preferably anything else I can stick a heat sink to): I plan to use a low-profile fan on it. Circulation is already bad enough in the laptop.

3) Finally, the battery must be **chargeable without taking it out** of the laptop: so I might need an Arduino battery charger like [this](https://www.adafruit.com/product/1904?gclid=EAIaIQobChMIzZyZwM7N5gIVj8hkCh34GAlfEAQYASABEgJGgfD_BwE).

LIke I said, I would like to hear your opinion on the project, and even better, how I should wire it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There are out-of-the-box solutions available for this. For instance joy-it.net has a solution with a HAT and a battery that can be used to power the Pi. It does cover the CPU though, but it should be possible to put a flat passive cooler on it and mount a fan at the edge of the board instead. That is, if it is required at all - the Pi doesn't necessarily need a fan.

Comment: Hi @PMF - I would accept your answer, but the more I research, the more I realize that for my project, I'll definitely need active cooling. Useful recommendation though.

Comment: I've read that they're trying to come up with a solution for the problem that their HAT prevents an active cooling. But I don't know how long that might take.

Comment: A copper plate might do better than a huge cpu cooling fan: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/106559/does-this-flat-plate-even-work-for-cooling